# How to convert integer to hex notation?

Tags: firebird

Using: Firebird 2.5.3

In a stored procedure (PSQL), converting a number from hex notation to decimal notation is done easily:

```
DECLARE VARIABLE I INTEGER;

BEGIN

  I = CAST('0x0FFFE' AS INTEGER);  -- I will have the value 65534
```

How can the reverse be achieved? ie. Convert from decimal notation to hex notation?

Comment: I don't believe there is such functionality; not without using an UDF or coding it yourself. BTW: The cast in your example code is not necessary if you remove the quotes as Firebird 2.5 introduced hexadecimal literals; see http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-hexnumerals.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of using a UDF (which would mean using an external library file), the solution is to write a stored procedure to accomplish this:

```
SET TERM ^^ ;
CREATE PROCEDURE INTTOHEX (
  INPUTNUMBER BigInt)
 returns (
  OUTPUTNUMBER VarChar(8))
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE Q BigInt;
DECLARE VARIABLE R BigInt;
DECLARE VARIABLE T BigInt;
DECLARE VARIABLE H VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE VARIABLE S VARCHAR(6);

begin
  /* Max input value allowed is: 4294967295 */

  S = 'ABCDEF';

  Q = 1;   
  OUTPUTNUMBER = '';
  T = INPUTNUMBER;
  WHILE (Q <> 0) DO
  BEGIN        

    Q = T / 16;
    R = MOD(T, 16);
    T = Q;

    IF (R > 9) THEN
     H = SUBSTRING(S FROM (R-9) FOR 1); 
    ELSE
     H = R;                                

    OUTPUTNUMBER = H || OUTPUTNUMBER ;
  END


  SUSPEND;
end ^^
SET TERM ; ^^
```

You can call this stored procedure from standard SQL or another stored procedure like this:

For example:

```
SELECT OUTPUTNUMBER FROM INTTOHEX(65534);
```

Answer (score 0):

just did a short firebird function,
could handle bigger number,
maybe could help someone

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION INT64TOHEX (
    C BIGINT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE IREM INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE HEX  VARCHAR(32);
BEGIN
  IREM = MOD(C, 0XFF);
  HEX = '';
  WHILE (IREM > 0) DO
  BEGIN
    HEX = SUBSTRING('0123456789abcdef' FROM BIN_SHR(BIN_AND(C, 0XFF), 4) + 1 FOR 1) || SUBSTRING('0123456789abcdef' FROM BIN_AND(BIN_AND(C, 0XFF), 15) + 1 FOR 1) || HEX;
    C = BIN_SHR(C, 8);
    IREM = MOD(C, 0XFF);
  END

  RETURN TRIM(HEX);
END
```